# Rust claims DashMap into_par_iter trait bounds not satisfied

Tags: rust, traits, rayon

For some time, my Rust program used a DashMap with a parallel iterator bridge. This was a major performance bottleneck, and I have just found that these days, DashMap supposedly supports direct parallel iteration. So I updated my dependency crates and changed my code. Now I have my `DashMap<K, V, S>` like this

```
let families_by_location: DashMap<
    petgraph::graph::NodeIndex<usize>,
    Vec<&mut Family>,
    std::hash::BuildHasherDefault<FxHasher>,
> = DashMap::default();

families_by_location.into_par_iter().map(...).collect();
```

However, this does not compile, and surprisingly, the error message is very unhelpful for me.

```
error[E0599]: the method `into_par_iter` exists for struct `dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:442:10
    |
442 |         .into_par_iter()
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /home/gereon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dashmap-5.2.0/src/lib.rs:67:1
    |
67  | pub struct DashMap<K, V, S = RandomState> {
    | -----------------------------------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
            `&dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `&dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
            `&mut dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `&mut dashmap::DashMap<NodeIndex<usize>, Vec<&mut Family>, BuildHasherDefault<rustc_hash::FxHasher>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `dispersal_model_rust` due to previous error
```

I also tried `families_by_location.par_iter_mut()` for a similarly unhelpful error concerning trait bounds.

I don't understand the issue. The trait bounds on DashMap<K, V, S> being an IntoParallelIterator are [`K: Send + Eq + Hash, V: Send, S: Send + Clone + BuildHasher`](https://docs.rs/dashmap/latest/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html#impl-IntoParallelIterator).
`K` is `NodeIndex<usize>`, which [implements `Send + Sync + Eq + Hash`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/graph/struct.NodeIndex.html) because [`usize` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#impl-Send).
The `FxHasher` Builder supposedly also supports `Send + Sync + Clone + BuildHasher`, and `Vec` is `Send + Sync` if its object type is. Now I would understand it if `&mut Family` is not `Send`, sending around mutable pointers between threads sounds dangerous. However, something like

```
let a: Vec<&mut Family> = families.par_iter_mut().collect();
let b: &dyn Sync = &a;
```

does no throw a compilation error, so it seems that `Vec<&mut Family>` is actually `Send + Sync`.

So it seems to me that the trait bounds for `DashMap<K, V, S>: IntoParallelIterator` trait bounds are fulfilled, why do I get the Rust compiler error?

Answer (score 0):

An old [comment on the DashMap issue tracker](https://github.com/xacrimon/dashmap/pull/116), which I found when searching for “parallel” on there, pointed out to me that activating the rayon feature is necessary. I did, and lo and behold my code compiles.

(I still find the error message which I get when not doing it quite confusing.)

While the list of feature flags on [dashmap's docs.rs page](https://docs.rs/crate/dashmap/latest/features) states

> ## rayon
>
> ---
>
> This feature flag does not enable additional features.

that statement is a bit misleading: As Kevin Reid pointed out, “unlike most of rustdoc and docs.rs content, there is no automatic reporting of what a feature flag does, except for enabling other feature flags.” So all this statement only means is that activating dashmap's rayon feature does not activate other feature flags.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no good way to auto-generate documentation for feature flags. When it says “does not enable additional features”, that text is strictly referring to _other feature flags._ docs.rs can't tell you anything about what changes the feature flag makes to the actual code.

Comment: @KevinReid Actually, there is a way, the [`doc(cfg)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/doc-cfg.html) attribute.

Comment: E.g. [in `tokio` source code](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/src/tokio/macros/cfg.rs.html#306).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That is _manual_ documentation for individual items. What I'm saying is that, unlike most of rustdoc and docs.rs content, there is no _automatic_ reporting of what a feature flag does, _except_ for enabling other feature flags. And in particular, [the docs.rs features page](https://docs.rs/crate/dashmap/latest/features) can't be customized at all, as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, okay! I'll keep that in mind when I read this kind of statement again in the future.